# How to create a dir tree in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, directory, mkdir

I want to create a simple dir tree in Windows using pure C. Heres what I did:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   if(CreateDirectory("testdir", NULL) == 0)
        printf("error!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Which works great. But this code, prints out an error - why?

```
#include<windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   if(CreateDirectory("testdir\\subdir", NULL) == 0)
        printf("error!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

According to [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), its the correct way to check if an error occured. Although, when I changed `\\` into `/` it seem not to work too:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   if(CreateDirectory("testdir/subdir", NULL) == 0)
        printf("error!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do what the docs say and use `GetLastError` to get more information?

Comment: Does testdir already exist or do you want to create the whole tree at once (what doesn't work AFAIK)?

Comment: Running your first program, followed by your second program worked for me. The second won't work without `testdir` being there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreateDirectory` function only creates the final directory of the path; if an intermediate directory is missing it returns zero and `GetLastError` will return `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you're not specifying a root directory. For instance, in your current context, if you want to create that folder, you should start the path with

```
 .\\testdir\\myotherfolder.
```

If you want to do it from c, you need to have

```
 c:\\testdir\\myotherfolder
```

Comment: It's fine how it is as long as `testdir` exists.